# Forwarding all mail in Gmail using using android app.

Tags: gmail

My father, nearly 80, has forgotten his gmail password and cannot recover it. However, it is saved on his android phone so he can access it on his phone, but not on a laptop he wishes to set up. I suggested he create a new gmail account and autoforward all mail from his current gmail (via his android phone) to his new gmail account.

How can he do this from his android gmail app? I can't find a universal forwarding option for mail to the account.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no option like this in the gmail app. You would have to log in on the website to change it, maybe the login is saved in the chrome app, so you can set up the automated forwarding there. 
You can even set up another e-mail in the accounts settings of your google account, where you could recover the mails. Just go to accounts.google.com on the phone and there you can set up a lot. 
But only, if the password is saved.

The only solution if the password is not saved would be:

- forward every existing mail to the new mail account
- create an automated answer for the old account with the new mailadress inside
- keep the old account still in gmail in case of any important mails
- transfer the accounts, which are linked to the old mail adress to the new by entering a new mailadress in the respective accounts (i.e. banking, news, amazon and so on)

Answer (score -3):

You can now use gmail multi email forward to do this

Comment: Hi! Can you provide instructions on how to do this? We prefer detailed answers. In need of assistance on answering, please visit our [help]. Thanks!

Comment: I failed to find if this is a native feature of Gmail for Android (I didn't see such thing), or even on Web. Looks like this needs [a Chrome extension](https://blog.cloudhq.net/forward-multiple-emails-gmail/) (which is not supported on Chrome for Android)?